# Android ActionBar Menu always showing overflow (Without AppCompat)

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, icons, overflow

[image]

No matter the screen size, the menu is always showing 3 dots instead of just showing a single icon on the right corner.

I have seen similar questions, but none of them without AppCompat.
I am using minSdkVersion 14 on my build.gradle file, and the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

Principal.Java relevant code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;

public class Principal extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar()
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
      return true;
  }
}
```

Here is my options_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_general">
     <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="@string/search_label"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/> 
</menu>
```

Comment: This is very simple you just need to add this attribute `app:showAsAction="always"` in item tag . The android:showAsAction attribute is available on Android 3.0 (API Level 11) and greater.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It still only renders the 3 dots.  Any other ideas?

Comment: you want to implement search view in action bar?

Comment: No.  It's just a search icon, but it triggers a different action.  It toggles a linearlayout visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the Method Oncreate:Change what u need

```
 Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
            topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the following property in your menuItem: 
            **app:showAsAction="always"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/menu_general">
          <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
                android:title="@string/search_label"
                app:showAsAction="always"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/> 
   </menu>
```

Comment: I'm afraid adding that line renders the same result.  Always the 3 dots.

Comment: Why dont you return: return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); instead of true? Did u add the xmlns:app namespace?

Comment: Yes.  I added xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to the xml file and returned the super.oncreateoptions but still the same result.